# Converting PHP date formats

Tags: php, date

I have a date that is currently formatted as 'y.m.d' and I need it formatted as 'D, M d, Y'. I've tried everything I can think of, but it always seems to get confused. Usually, a date that is listed as '11.11.27' comes out as 'Wed, Dec 31, 1969' somehow... Any thoughts as to why that happens (really? 1969??) or how to properly perform this conversion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code you are using to generate the formatted date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method.

For example:

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('y.m.d', '11.12.03');
echo $date->format('D, M d, Y');
?>
```

Comment: Note that’ll require PHP 5.3, which your server may not have been upgraded too yet.

Comment: PHP 5.2 has been dead for a long time - http://www.php.net/archive/2010.php#id2010-12-16-1. I don't think it is necessary to caveat 5.3 functions any more with 5.4 on the way as well. Besides it is clearly stated in the manual page I have linked to.

Comment: Lol, I use many servers still running 5.2!

Comment: @IanJamieson Support ended very nearly one year ago in December. I don't think every answer that mentions a PHP5.3 function or constant should have to be caveated any more. Many of us still run 5.2 servers out of necessity, but it is up to us to check given that we are the ones running antiquated software.

Comment: That's perfect on my server... now if the server that I'm writing the script for has PHP 5.3 we'll be in business! Thanks!

Comment: Without offence to @Ghost1227, some beginners don’t realise that there has been an update and don’t know which version their shared hosting uses, so I thought I’d add the note incase it wasn’t working for them :)

Comment: No offence taken... I don't use shared hosting though ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
echo date('D, M d, Y', strtotime(str_replace('.','-',$yourDate)));
```